# Array push is getting just 1 object codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this **model**(for the sake of clarity I only posted relevant parts to my problem):

```
public function getMissedEntryesForInterval($from_date, $to_date){

  $missedEntryObject = null;
  if(isset($from_date, $to_date)){
      $missedEntryObject = new MissedInsertions_model;
      $missedEntryObject->entryId=0;
      $missedEntryObject->entryWeight=0;
      $missedEntryObject->entryEventType=0;
      $missedEntryObject->entryInsertBy=0;
      $missedEntryObject->entryModifiedDate=0;
      foreach ($finallist as $inputElement) {
          if (5000 <= (int)$inputElement->weight) {
              $this->_agregateRowToEntry($missedEntryObject, $inputElement);
        } 
      }
  return $missedEntryObject;
    }
private function _agregateRowToEntry($entryObject, $input){
    $entryObject->entryId = $input->id;
    $entryObject->entryWeight = $input->weight;
    $entryObject->entryEventType = $input->etid;
    $entryObject->entryInsertBy = $input->insert_by;
    $entryObject->entryModifiedDate = $input->modified_date;
}
public function jsonSerialize() {
    return [
        'entry_id' => $this->entryId,
        'entry_weight' => $this->entryWeight,
        'entry_event' => $this->entryEventType,
        'entry_insert_by' => $this->entryInsertBy,
        'entry_modified_date' => $this->entryModifiedDate
    ];

}
```

My $finallist (for my start time end time in postman) is looking like this:

```
[{"id":"58560","weight":"2160","added_date":"2016-08-14 09:01:58","etid":"3","insert_by":"1","modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"},{"id":"58588","weight":"4300","added_date":"2016-08-14 09:23:23","etid":"3","insert_by":"1","modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"},{"id":"58862","weight":"40800","added_date":"2016-08-14 15:24:21","etid":"3","insert_by":"1","modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"},{"id":"59521","weight":"38780","added_date":"2016-08-15 11:42:06","etid":"3","insert_by":"1","modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"},{"id":"60176","weight":"45260","added_date":"2016-08-15 19:48:20","etid":"3","insert_by":"1","modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"},{"id":"60389","weight":"38780","added_date":"2016-08-16 11:18:44","etid":"3","insert_by":"1","modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"},{"id":"61730","weight":"42380","added_date":"2016-08-16 19:15:22","etid":"3","insert_by":"1","modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"},{"id":"62369","weight":"42800","added_date":"2016-08-17 15:25:46","etid":"3","insert_by":"1","modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"}]
```

And in my controller I call this like :

```
public function getMissedBalanceEventsNew() {
    $from_date = $this->input->post('startDate');
    $to_date = $this->input->post('endDate');

    $result[] = $this->MissedInsertions_model->getMissedEntryesForInterval($from_date,$to_date);

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

But I only get this object when I call the model in controller:

```
[{"entry_id":"62369","entry_weight":"42800","entry_event":"3","entry_insert_by":"1","entry_modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"}]
```

Desired is this :

```
[{"entry_id":"58862","weight":"40800","entry_event":"3","entry_insert_by":"1","entry_modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"},{"entry_id":"58862","entry_weight":"40800","entry_event":"3","entry_insert_by":"1","entry_modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"},{"entry_id":"59521","entry_weight":"38780","entry_insert_by":"1","entry_modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"},{"entry_id":"60176","entry_weight":"45260","entry_event":"3","entry_insert_by":"1","entry_modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"},{"id":"60389","entry_weight":"38780","entry_event":"3","entry_insert_by":"1","entry_modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"},{"entry_id":"61730","entry_weight":"42380","entry_event":"3","entry_insert_by":"1","entry_modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"},{"entry_id":"62369","entry_weight":"42800","entry_event":"3","entry_insert_by":"1","entry_modified_date":"2017-04-04 12:26:05"}]
```

Basically I want to get all the object from $finallist that have weight >5000 in my list in controller. I think I have to do some sort of for loop in controller, but what exactly so that my list wont be replaced with 1 object ? Thanks!

Comment: I have the foreach in my model, that iterates the list, but my problem is that in controller list I would get the last object, (objects are just replacing, and I remain with the last one).

Comment: I saw, that's why I removed the comment. ;-) A question, this isn't all the code, right? I mean: `foreach ($finallist as $inputElement)` shouldn't work since you never define the `$finallist` variable?

Comment: No, I did not put all the business logic as it isn't related to my problem.

Comment: You are using one single object($missedEntryObject) to allocate multiple values. And that's why the last value is shown. Create object array for this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your model. There you overwrite the object returned and because of that you get only the values for the last object.

Try something like this:

```
public function getMissedEntryesForInterval($from_date, $to_date){

  $missedEntryObject = null;
  if(isset($from_date, $to_date)){
      $missedEntryObject = new MissedInsertions_model;
      $finalObjects = array();
      $missedEntryObject->entryId=0;
      $missedEntryObject->entryWeight=0;
      $missedEntryObject->entryEventType=0;
      $missedEntryObject->entryInsertBy=0;
      $missedEntryObject->entryModifiedDate=0;
      foreach ($finallist as $inputElement) {
          if (5000 <= (int)$inputElement->weight) {
             $this->_agregateRowToEntry($missedEntryObject, $inputElement);
        } 
      }
      return $finalObjects;
    }
```

LE:

```
foreach ($finallist as $inputElement) {
              if (5000 <= (int)$inputElement->weight) {
                $this->_agregateRowToEntry($missedEntryObject, $inputElement);
                $finalObjects[] = $missedEntryObject;
            }
```

Comment: Don't forget to change `$result = $this->MissedInsertions...` to `$result = $this->MissedInsertions...`.

Comment: $missedEntryObject is my class instance object, I want to return that, and make the append in my controller, anyway your suggestion is returning null!

Comment: Oh, I see now. My bad. In foreach you should do:
$this->_agregateRowToEntry($missedEntryObject, $inputElement);
$finalObjects[] = $missedEntryObject;